# Formik form submission with custom handler with react-testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am looking to fire a submit handler for a LoginForm. I am using MUI with Formik. I am trying to mock submit handler but "handleSubmit" handler is never getting fired. How can I ensure that my mock handler gets called instead?

Is there is a way to achieve this ??

```
const Login = () => {

const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    ..... // submit logic
};

return (
 <Grid item xs={12}>
  <Formik
        initialValues={{
        username: '',
        password: '',
        submit: null
        }}
        validationSchema={LoginValidationSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
   >
    {({ errors, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, touched, values }) => (
        <form data-testid="login-form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormControl fullWidth error={Boolean(touched.username && errors.username)}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="username">Email Address / Username</InputLabel>
                <OutlinedInput
                    id="username"
                    type="email"
                    value={values.username}
                    name="username"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label="Email Address / Username"
                    inputProps={{}}
                />
                {touched.username && errors.username && (
                    <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-username">
                        {errors.username}
                    </FormHelperText>
                )}
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth error={Boolean(touched.password && errors.password)}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                <OutlinedInput
                    id="password"
                    type="password"
                    value={values.password}
                    name="password"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label="Password"
                    inputProps={{}}
                />
                {touched.password && errors.password && (
                    <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-password">
                        {errors.password}
                    </FormHelperText>
                )}
            </FormControl>
            {errors.submit && (
                <Box>
                    <FormHelperText error>{errors.submit}</FormHelperText>
                </Box>
            )}
            <Box>
                    <Button
                        data-testid="login"
                        disableElevation
                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                        fullWidth
                        size="large"
                        type="submit"
                        variant="contained"
                    >
                        Sign in
                    </Button>
            </Box>
        </form>
   )}
   </Formik>                                
  </Grid>
 )
};

export default Login;
```

What I Tried so far:

```
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId, getLabelByText } = wrapper;

    formData = { email: 'username', password: 'password' };
    emailInput = getByLabelText('Email Address / Username');
    passwordInput = getByLabelText('Password');
    loginButtonNode = wrapper.getByText('Sign in') as HTMLElement;

    await waitFor(() => {
        fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: formData.email } });
        fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: formData.password } });
    });
    
    act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(getByTestId('login'));
    });

    // throws error
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            username: 'username,
            password: 'password'
        });
    });


    // throws error
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

// throws error
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, Formik only calls onSubmit when the formdata validates.
So something being not valid yet in your form probably cause it never getting called.

It's hard to give a better answer since I have no clue what your `LoginValidationSchema` is. My guess would be that you have email validation in place so `fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: formData.email } });`  would not actually be valid (because formData.email === 'email').

Comment: You might want to describe how to fix the problem then. Or in case you did not mean to answer and want the question answered (which I edited away) you should delete this and use your commenting privilege.

Comment: Not sure if this is better... not much more I can give on the subject